# docker with python3 and django production image?

Tags: python, django, docker

Does anyone use docker for a production image of Django, and how do you build that box?

I'm using the base python image with a requirements.txt for development. but id like to use a docker image for production too, but appreciate a web server should be used for this. I've used apache in the past. is there a good approach to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using Docker in production with Django. There is not only one valid approach, but there are some components (Docker images) that you're going to need.

1. **WSGI server:** This will serve your Django application. Personally, I use gunicorn, but there are other good options.
2. **Web server:** You could use the WSGI server to serve your static files, but that's not recommended in production. I use nginx to this, but almost any web server will be suitable for this task. Take a look to this section at Django documentation about serving static files in production (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/)
3. **Database**: Unless your Django app is really simple, you'll need a database.

This are the basic components that you are going to need in a Django app. Each one of this should be a Docker image.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: can docker create a container reference multiple images? how do I create a container that uses python3, gunicorn,ngnix and Django?

Comment: No, the best approach is using a different image for each service. You can't create a container referencing multiple images. It seems that you don't have concepts of image and container clear, so I recommend you to read Docker docs (https://docs.docker.com/), and then follow this tutorial (http://ruddra.com/2016/08/14/docker-django-nginx-postgres/).